# Как обезопасить базу данных на удаленном сервере!

Tags: python, база-данных, безопасность

Раньше никогда не работал с базами данных. Сейчас возникла задача наполнять базу данных на удаленном сервере через приложение, которое написано на Python. Приложением будут пользоваться разово, но достаточно большое количество людей. В базе будут хранится конфиденциальныё данные пользователей. Ну, и возникает, вопрос: как обезопасить пароль и адрес базы в исходных кодах Python, если при подключении к удаленной базе нужно явно указывать адрес и пароль. Как это делают? Нужно ли код подключения выносить в Си расширения или шифровать базу? Подскажите?

Comment: Для таких целей реализовывают API. Далее приложение работает с этим API. Никакие данные от БД хранить в коде приложения ни в коем случае нельзя. Пользователь в приложении авторизовывается, получает токен, а дальше этот токен шлется каждый раз вместе с запросом. Токен позволит контролировать на сервере доступы.